# get_filtered_term_product_counts - Get product terms if any products

Tags: php, wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to produce an API that basically delivers the same results as the "archive" search page, with their widgets, to say, show terms that matches the queried products. So for instance, if you query products with a specific category, only the terms associated with products in that category will be shown.

All this logic is based in the class `WC_Widget_Layered_Nav`, more specifically in the `get_filtered_term_product_counts` method.

However, it's a private method. So I might need to rewrite everything myself. Or would there be a way to do this smarter?

Question: How can I retrieve specific product attributes & categories ONLY if they exist within the queried resultset?

I guess I can't be the first to develop an API for WooCommerce where this is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I realized there's no open API for WooCommerce that can handle this, and my research declared that there were nobody else doing this. At least not to my knowledge.

So I created the code, and it works. I'll share my code in case anybody else would like to use WordPress as a headless CMS where WooCommerce is installed.

The code is not that pretty, but it does the job, and I'm happy with the result:

https://gist.github.com/simplenotezy/b0eb1552c12fd13a46c8683fb79c3d6c

```
<?php
/**
 * This allows you to get the archive page / shop page data through the WordPress REST APi.
 * It's not beautiful, but it works.
 *
 * The REST URL: https://yourwebsite.com/wp-json/custom-woocommerce/v1/shop/slug
 * 
 * Parameters:
 * "filter_{attribute_name}=some_value", e.g. "/shop/?filter_color=red". You can filter multiple values: ?filter_color=red,blue&filter_size=1,2
 * "categories", e.g. "/shop/?categories=shoes,shirts&filter_color=blue"
 *
 * The response will be your products, as well as a key called "filters". This contains all relevant filters related to the _specific query_ you just made.
 */

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
register_rest_route( 'custom-woocommerce/v1', '/shop/(?P<slug>\S+)', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => function($data) {

    $page = (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
    $seed = (isset($_GET['seed']) && $_GET['seed']) ? $_GET['seed'] : rand(11111,99999);

    $args = [
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 12,
        'orderby' => 'RAND(' . $seed . ')',
        'tax_query' => ['relation' => 'AND'],
        'page' => $page
    ];

    $response = [
        'seed' => $seed
    ];

    /**
     * Search product attributes
     */

    $public_wc_taxonomies = array_values(array_map(function($taxonomy) {
        return 'pa_' . $taxonomy->attribute_name;
    }, array_filter(wc_get_attribute_taxonomies(), function($taxonomy) {
        return $taxonomy->attribute_public;
    })));

    $taxonomies = [];

    foreach($_GET as $getParameter => $attribute_slugs) {

        if(substr( $getParameter, 0, 7 ) === "filter_") {
            if(!isset($attribute_tax_query))
            $attribute_tax_query = ['relation' => 'OR'];


            $attribute_slugs = explode(',', $attribute_slugs);

            $taxonomy = str_replace('filter_', 'pa_', $getParameter);

            foreach($attribute_slugs as $attribute_slug) {
            $taxonomies[$taxonomy][] = get_term_by('slug', $attribute_slug, $taxonomy);

            $attribute_tax_query[] = [
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $attribute_slug
            ];
            }
        }
    }

    if(isset($attribute_tax_query))
        $args['tax_query'][] = $attribute_tax_query;

    /**
     * Search categories
     */

        if(isset($_GET['categories'])) {
        $cats = explode(',', $_GET['categories']);
        $categories = [];

        $category_tax_query = ['relation' => 'OR'];


        foreach($cats as $category_slug) {
            $category = get_term_by('slug', $category_slug, 'product_cat');

            if(!$category)
            continue; // we couldn't find a category with that slug

            $categories[] = [
            'name' => $category->name,
            'slug' => $category->slug,
            'count' => $category->count,
            ];

            $category_tax_query[] = [
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $category_slug
            ];
        }

        $args['tax_query'][] = $category_tax_query;

        $response['categories'] = $categories;
        }


    $query = new WP_Query($args);


    $response['products'] = $query->posts;

    /**
     * If this is the first page, output attributes related to this search
     */

        if($args['page'] == 1) {
        global $wp_the_query;
        $wp_the_query = $query; // little hack to get interals of WooCommerce to function properly
        (wc())->query->pre_get_posts($wp_the_query);

        foreach($public_wc_taxonomies as $taxonomy) {
            $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, array( 'hide_empty' => '1' ) );

            $response['filters'][$taxonomy] = get_terms_and_count_for_current_query($terms, $taxonomy, (isset($args['tax_query'][0]['relation'])) ? $args['tax_query'][0]['relation'] : 'OR');

            if(!$response['filters'][$taxonomy]) {
            unset($response['filters'][$taxonomy]);
            }
        }
        }

    /**
     * Outut categories if they are not yet requested
     */

    if(!isset($_GET['categories'])) {
        $response['filters']['product_cat'] = get_terms_and_count_for_current_query(get_terms( 'product_cat', array( 'hide_empty' => '1' ) ), 'product_cat', 'or');
    }

    return $response;
    }));
});

/**
 * Code mostly copied from WooCommerce internals, then adjusted.
 * The reason for this is, that their API is private, so you can't access it outside without even nastier hacks
 * So. I did a bit of workarounds to get the right response..
 */

function wc_get_filtered_term_product_counts($term_ids, $taxonomy, $query_type = 'or') {
global $wpdb;

$tax_query  = WC_Query::get_main_tax_query();
$meta_query = WC_Query::get_main_meta_query();

if ( 'or' === $query_type ) {
    foreach ( $tax_query as $key => $query ) {
    if ( isset($query['taxonomy']) && is_array( $query ) && $taxonomy === $query['taxonomy'] ) {
        unset( $tax_query[ $key ] );
    }
    }
}

$meta_query     = new WP_Meta_Query( $meta_query );
$tax_query      = new WP_Tax_Query( $tax_query );
$meta_query_sql = $meta_query->get_sql( 'post', $wpdb->posts, 'ID' );
$tax_query_sql  = $tax_query->get_sql( $wpdb->posts, 'ID' );

// Generate query.
$query           = array();
$query['select'] = "SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT {$wpdb->posts}.ID ) as term_count, terms.term_id as term_count_id";
$query['from']   = "FROM {$wpdb->posts}";
$query['join']   = "
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} AS term_relationships ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID = term_relationships.object_id
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} AS term_taxonomy USING( term_taxonomy_id )
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->terms} AS terms USING( term_id )
    " . $tax_query_sql['join'] . $meta_query_sql['join'];

$query['where'] = "
    WHERE {$wpdb->posts}.post_type IN ( 'product' )
    AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_status = 'publish'"
    . $tax_query_sql['where'] . $meta_query_sql['where'] .
    'AND terms.term_id IN (' . implode( ',', array_map( 'absint', $term_ids ) ) . ')';

$search = WC_Query::get_main_search_query_sql();
if ( $search ) {
    $query['where'] .= ' AND ' . $search;
}

$query['group_by'] = 'GROUP BY terms.term_id';
$query             = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_filtered_term_product_counts_query', $query );
$query             = implode( ' ', $query );

// We have a query - let's see if cached results of this query already exist.
$query_hash = md5( $query );

// Maybe store a transient of the count values.
$cache = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_layered_nav_count_maybe_cache', true );
if ( true === $cache ) {
    $cached_counts = (array) get_transient( 'wc_layered_nav_counts_' . sanitize_title( $taxonomy ) );
} else {
    $cached_counts = array();
}

if ( ! isset( $cached_counts[ $query_hash ] ) ) {
    $results                      = $wpdb->get_results( $query, ARRAY_A ); // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine
    $counts                       = array_map( 'absint', wp_list_pluck( $results, 'term_count', 'term_count_id' ) );
    $cached_counts[ $query_hash ] = $counts;
    if ( true === $cache ) {
    set_transient( 'wc_layered_nav_counts_' . sanitize_title( $taxonomy ), $cached_counts, DAY_IN_SECONDS );
    }
}

return array_map( 'absint', (array) $cached_counts[ $query_hash ] );
}

function get_terms_and_count_for_current_query($terms, $taxonomy, $query_type = 'or') {

    $term_counts        = wc_get_filtered_term_product_counts( wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'term_id' ), $taxonomy, $query_type );
    $_chosen_attributes = WC_Query::get_layered_nav_chosen_attributes();
    $found              = false;

    $return_terms = [];

        foreach ( $terms as $index => $term ) {
            $current_values = isset( $_chosen_attributes[ $taxonomy ]['terms'] ) ? $_chosen_attributes[ $taxonomy ]['terms'] : array();
    $option_is_set  = in_array( $term->slug, $current_values, true );
            $count          = isset( $term_counts[ $term->term_id ] ) ? $term_counts[ $term->term_id ] : 0;

    if ( 0 < $count ) {
                $found = true;
            } elseif ( 0 === $count && ! $option_is_set ) {
                continue;
            }

            $return_terms[] = [
                'name' => html_entity_decode ($term->name),
                'slug' => $term->slug,
                'taxonomy' => $term->taxonomy,
                'count' => $count,
                'is_set' => $option_is_set
            ];
        }

        return $return_terms;
}
```